# Why I need "Connect Salesforce Authenticator" during activation of "myDomain"?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, security, mydomain

I'm working on a Sandbox and I need to use Custom Lightning Components.

Therefore I need to activate the myDomain feature.

I've done that several times before, but today I get stuck in the process. First I've picked a domain-name and checked its availability. After Salesforce has confirmed the availability, I have to test-login and see this screen:

[image]

Now (still as usual) I have to click the "Log in"-Button in order to test it out. When I do this, something new and for me unexpected happens. I see this screen:

[image]

I started to read this [documentation here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesforce_authenticator_how_to_download.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.7), but it would take me a deeper dive to understand it's purpose. Now my questions are:

- Why I have to deal with this feature just to get myDomain (only needed to use Lightning Components) up and running?
- I am not a solo developer on this Org: there are several developer teams and some key-users working on this sandbox as well. Will this have an impact which goes beyond the "myDomain" activation process, I have to be aware of?
- did anyone of you encounter any new (negative) side-effects after providing the "Two-Word Passphrase" and click "Connect"?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the org you are using is having 2 factor authentication and its authentication has been set via authenticator app so you are receiving this error.
First of all you will have to remove two factor authentication.

Follow the following steps:

1. Go to “Administrative Setup” and then “Manage Users” and “Profiles.”
2. Uncheck the “Two-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins” permission

Then try.