# Is it possible to disable Salesforce Authenticator App completely?

Tags: security, authentication, login

Some time ago I had to enable the MyDomain Feature in order to enable custom lightning components on a Sandbox-Org as described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177616/why-i-need-connect-salesforce-authenticator-during-activation-of-mydomain). Until that the two factor authentication was working with password and security codes send by email until then - which was the desired and expected situation.

During the activation of MyDomain this method was replaced unasked and unwanted so that now no longer a code is send by email but users are forced to use the Salesforce Authenticator App installed on a mobile device.

We don't want to use this mechanism and the app, because we don't like it at all. Is there any way to completely disable this method and go back to security codes via email?

It looks like this on the desktop:

[image]

It seems to offer a way out (Link "Use a different Verification Method" in the bottom)

[image]

But neither of the option is what we are looking for

[image]

I have tried to find a way to configure it reading the documentation here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=basics_identity.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.8

But I was not able to find a setting to get rid of the Authenticator App again.

Comment: Check any permission set is not defined with 2FA enabled. If it is then edit the permission set, or you can remove users from that permission set.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar - So if on one permission set 2FA is not enabled, the Authenticator App is just "jumping in"? And this happens just unasked, unwanted and undocumented? Hard to believe... And why did the Authenticator App starts anoying just during MyDomain activation, while the org was working before with the security codes by email? There were NO CHANGES AT ALL on permission sets nor on profiles? Do you have any link to further documentation on why you are suggesting to check the permission sets? Or is this just your guess?

Comment: This is not a guess, AFAIK there is a way to setup 2FA using permission sets - so just to have check i suggested to check permission sets https://automationchampion.com/2013/10/17/two-factor-authentication-in-salesforce/

Comment: I assume you checked all session settings? https://i.imgur.com/f4uWICF.png
This does not seem related to mydomain to me but rather a new quirk. there's another known issue aronud identity currently: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CiWQAU&title=login-as-user-in-lightning-with-lock-session-to-domain-invalidate-session-quickly

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but had to disconnect the app for a user in order to allow her to authenticate without the app so I figured I would reply.

The system administrator can disconnect app from the user profile.  On the user profile, find "App Registration: Salesforce Authenticator" and then hit "disconnect".

Answer (score 0):

You may have to disable the "Multi-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins" on the User profile.

I couldn't find an adequate support document on turning off the Authenticator connection either.  One article mentions only disconnecting Authenticator in the Personal Settings.  Another mentions disconnecting only the User Settings.  But you ALSO have to disconnect the "Multi-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins" in the Profile Settings.  Until I found the Profile Settings, disconnecting the Authenticator on the Personal or User Settings seemed to work for a second, but when I refreshed the pages it was connected again.  Support needs to mention all three means of disconnecting.  Because as we get closer to the MFA deadline, a lot more users will be stumble in the web of MFA and want out.

Answer (score 0):

[image: MFA disable setting]

Here is a setting which allows to disable MFA. However, if I understood correctly, Salesforce will force MFA for all customers gradually, and the whole customer base will be moved to it by spring 2024.

However, there is an option to bypass MFA by creating a separate user permission set, you can check the details here :
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_mfa_exclude_exempt_users.htm